# Play audio on keypress

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to create a script that will play an audio and close the player when it finishes. I've managed to assign it to a key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd>:

```
target_app = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe"
target_filepath = "C:\some_audio.mp3"
^NumpadMult::Run, %target_app% %target_filepath%
```

This just starts Windows Media Player and plays the audio, but the player still stays open after the audio is done playing. I also want to close the player.

I've just started using AutoHotkey and don't know my way around. I need to do the following ops:

- read the duration of the audio (**✗**)
- set a timeout (using audio duration) (**✗**)

  - close the player (**✗**)
- run the player and play the audio (**✓**)

How can I do this?

Comment: Check the [SoundPlay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundPlay.htm) command, it might make thing easier.

Comment: @Yane I'm glad there's a built-in method to do this. It's working fine: `^NumpadMult::SoundPlay, C:\space test\invalid_keypress.mp3, 1`. It seems there's no need to quote space-containing paths (at least in this case).

Comment: SoundPlay will not work everytime, it may also depend what your codec can play

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you want to check audio duration:

```
GetAudioDuration( mFile ) {
    VarSetCapacity( DN, 16 ), DLLFunc := "winmm.dll\mciSendString" ( A_IsUnicode ? "W" : "A" )
    DllCall( DLLFunc, Str, "open " """" mFile """" " Alias MP3", UInt, 0, UInt, 0, UInt, 0 )
    DllCall( DLLFunc, Str, "status MP3 length", Str, DN, UInt, 16, UInt, 0 )
    DllCall( DLLFunc, Str, "close MP3", UInt, 0, UInt, 0, UInt, 0 )
    Return DN
}

MsgBox, % GetAudioDuration( "C:\WINDOWS\Media\ding.wav" ) ; returns 397 (Windows 10)
```

[Original Post](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/54686-help-audiogenie-calculate-duration-and-save-thats-all/#entry343211)